# Serilog - GetRequiredService<ILogger<T>> vs Log.ForContext<T>

Tags: c#, .net, logging, dependency-injection, serilog

What is the difference between

```
var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<T>>;
```

vs

```
var logger = Log.ForContext<T>();
```

Comment: At the very least, there's no `ILogger<T>` in Serilog, so you're getting two different interfaces here. I suspect the first one is Microsoft's abstraction. [This thread](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/104) might be of interest.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a duplicate too. There's also longer versions of that github discussion. The TL;DR of them all is For apps: you can pick either 1. using MS ILogger and DI or 2. use the Serilog `static Log` - both strategies have significant usage. For libraries: 1. you don't want to use static things 2. If you are doing a lib coupling to Serilog is definitely more debatable than it is for an app 3. you don't want them to take stuff from DI - take either Serilog ILogger or MS ILogger.